# Getting char * from C++ DLL to C# application

Tags: c#, c++

I have exported function in C++ DLL:

```
extern "C" int _stdcall info(int aError, char * description, int *aLen)
```

Trying to call it from C# application.

Declaring:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] public static extern int info(int aError,   StringBuilder description, ref int length);
```

Calling:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
fr = info(5, buffer, ref 256);
```

From first point of view seems this works. But is it really safe? I mean will `StringBuilder` always manage enaugh memory for string that comes from `info` to `buffer` variable?

I write `StringBuilder description` in declaration, should I add `ref`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean will StringBuilder always manage enough memory for string that comes from info to buffer variable?

You should always specify the initial capacity of the StringBuilder by using the constructor that takes the capacity:

```
int size = 256;
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(256);
fr = info(5, buffer, ref size);
```

Comment: But I didn't passed and has no problem. Why?

Comment: @vico the string builder has an initial capacity (I don't know exactly how much) so the buffer may have been big enough in the first place.

Comment: And in declaration I write 'StringBuilder description', should I add 'ref'

Comment: No, StringBuilder is already a reference type and is marshaled as [In, Out] by default. Using ref would imply the native type is `char**`

Comment: The initial capacity of string builder is 16 but it will be auto-increased when required if the capacity is not specified, infinitely. Look the DefaultCapacity variable and the default constructor at the [reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs)

Comment: By the way, passing a constant value as ref will not compile: ref 256

Comment: @OguzOzgul I fixed the constant by ref, it was like that just for illustration. The "auto sizing" of the StringBuilder does not matter when it is used for Platform Invoke - the internal buffer must be big enough to fit the native callee's expectations.

Comment: @vcsjones I think It's the job of COM Interop to appropriately copy the contents of the char* into the StringBuilder. In this case, it is probably not just copying the whole buffer of [char *] into the string builder in one shot, but preparing the String Builder instance first. (you pass string builder by reference. What if it already contains data? The data should be cleared first).

Comment: @OguzOzgul Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah6xy75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx in general and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx in particular.